# SSRS Hide Column Based on Drill Down Level

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have a ssrs reports with 3 row groups and 2 columns. e.g. Continent > Country > City | Sales | Tax

The user drills down from Continent to Country to City.  They can always see Sales and Tax.

i want to hide the tax column when the user drills down to the city level (click + sign on country).

I have tried setting the column visibility based on a expression
e.g. =IIF(CountRows("City")>0,False,True).  But this gives me an error relating to scope.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: How do you achieve the drill down?

Comment: I use row grouping to achieve the drill down. I have 3 row groups. Continent, Country and City.